# When dealing with Razor Pages and a Page Model class is the constructor called on each request?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

Something I have struggled with is understanding the lifecycle of the Page Model class for my Razor Pages usages. I'm trying to think about how and when to deal with common data I pass to my business logic like the userId that is running the request. So many times I need to save this information with the results of the action.

So where is the best place to handle something over and over like geting User details that might be in the persistence model and not in the context of the page model's User from the HTTPContext?

I should mention I am using authorize tags with cookie backed authenication to a webservice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For accessing Reuqest from other layers except the `Razor Page`, you could try `IHttpContextAccessor`.

For general way to handling user details from request, you could create a service like below:

```
public interface IUserService
{
    IdentityUser GetUser();
}

public class UserService:IUserService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;

    public UserService(ApplicationDbContext context
        , IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _context = context;
        _httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }
    public IdentityUser GetUser()
    {
        StringValues userId = "";
        if (_httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("userId", out userId))
        {
            var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
            return user;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And then register like

```
    services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
```

Then, you could resolve `IUserService` from DI to use them when you want to access user info.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public IndexModel(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        var user = _userService.GetUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I like this idea. I still feel there is too much boilerplate code that I never seem to know where to put!

Comment: @PaulDuer Where did you want to access user details?

Comment: Basically so many times in a request method like OnPost this our OnPut that I need to get the httpcontext user and then return my system user. I wanted a faster way to just always have that ready.